# NavigableMap support in Chronicle-Map ?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-map

Thanks in advance for your support.

Is there any way to create java NavigableMap in Chronicle-Map ?

Answer (score 2):

No, because Chronicle Map is a hash-based shared nothing data structure, i. e. it's more like HashMap than TreeMap in Java. For fast persistent data store that stores the keys in order, I recommend LMDB (check out https://github.com/lmdbjava/lmdbjava), however I'm not sure it provides `NavigableMap` interface out of the box.